# curl unathorized and (23) failed writing body

Tags: api, curl, error-handling

I'm trying to follow this example, but i'm stucked on **Get Scooter Locations**
https://github.com/ubahnverleih/WoBike/blob/master/Beam.md

I get the access code, but when I try to get scooter location, it fails
Here's the code I wrote

```
curl --request GET \
--url 'https://gateway.ridebeam.com/api/vehicles/getForH3/rider/detail' \
--header 'User-Agent: escooterapp/latest-app-version; ios' \
--header 'Authorization: <access code>' | jq''
```

The result of this code is,

```
{
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "messageKey": "",
  "messageArgs": {}
}
```

I thought it will get authorization as I paste access code, but it doesn't.

If I type like this,

```
curl --request GET \
--url 'https://gateway.ridebeam.com/api/vehicles/getForH3/rider/detail/{"latitude":"latitude", "longitude":"longitude"}' \
--header 'User-Agent: escooterapp/latest-app-version; ios' \
--header 'Authorization: <access code>' | jq''
```

the result is,

```
[1/2]: https://gateway.ridebeam.com/api/vehicles/getForH3/rider/detail/"latitude":"0" --> <stdout>
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    59  100    59    0     0    210      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   210
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 16

[2/2]: https://gateway.ridebeam.com/api/vehicles/getForH3/rider/detail/ "longitude":"0" --> <stdout>
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   273  100   273    0     0   2814      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2814
(23) Failed writing body
```

it makes (23) error. I can't figure out what is wrong with code. Or did api block this curl?

Answer (score 0):

First, drop `--request GET` from the command line since curl uses GET by default anyway.

Then: the use of `{}` in the URL causes curl to do [globbing](https://everything.curl.dev/cmdline/globbing) on it, and you don't want that for this. Switch it off using curl's [-g/--globoff](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-g)

But more importantly: the [docs for the API](https://github.com/ubahnverleih/WoBike/blob/master/Beam.md#get-scooter-locations) seems to say that 'lattitude' and 'longitude' should be URL parameters, not passed as JSON in the URL. So asking for latitude 22 and longitude 23 might look like this:

```
curl \
--url "https://gateway.ridebeam.com/api/vehicles/getForH3/rider/detail/?latitude=22&longitude=23" \
--header 'User-Agent: escooterapp/latest-app-version; ios' \
--header 'Authorization: <access code>' | jq''
```

The fact that the server reports "unauthorized" is probably because you don't provide the correct authorization/headers but as you pass on such a header I suspect you just do it wrongly (like maybe using a wrong "access code") and that the server detects that.

Comment: thank you for answer, but it still reports unauthorized. i think i wrote the whole header that suggest in github post. i can't figure out what i missed...

Comment: would it be i posted wrong access code?

Comment: I think that is likely, yes